# Values larger than Int32.Max are truncated in Microsoft Graph API for Excel

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the Microsoft Graph API to modify cells in Excel spreadsheets. When writing integer values larger than `Int32.Max` to the spreadsheet via the API, the upper 32 bits of the values appear to be truncated, and only the lower 32 bits seem to be written to the spreadsheet.

Below are the values that I have tested.

Test 1:

```
Value sent: 1,234,000,000,000 (0x11F5021B400)
Value written to cell: 1344386048 (0x5021B400)
```

The upper bits appear to have been truncated, leaving behind only the lower 32 bits.

Test 2:

```
Value sent: 2,147,483,648 (Int32.Max + 1) (0x80000000)
Value written to the cell: -2147483648
```

If `0x80000000` is interpreted as a signed Int32 number, then it is `-2147483648`

Test 3:

```
Value sent: 4294967296 (0x100000000)
Value written to the cell: 0
```

When the highest bit of `0x100000000` is truncated, the remaining 32 bits become `0` in signed Int32

Test 4:

```
Value sent: 4294967295 (0xFFFFFFFF)
Value written to the cell: -1
```

When interpreted as a signed Int32 value, `0xFFFFFFFF` becomes `-1`

All of the values were sent using the .NET Microsoft Graph Client library. All of the values sent were of type long. Setting the value type in the request to Double did not fix the problem.

Since Excel spreadsheets support values larger than `Int32.Max`, I would expect the Microsoft Graph API to also support this. Any help or response would be much appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the SDK rather than the API itself. You can log issues with the C# SDK team on GitHub: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Thank you for the suggestion. I have reported the issue.

Comment: Update: after using Fiddler to examine the requests sent with the SDK, I found out that the long integers were not truncated in the requests. However, in the response received, the integers were all truncated. This seems to suggest that the problem is actually in the Excel service itself, not the SDK. The SDK team has also labelled this issue a service bug, and is still investigating.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft team's proposed solution is to send numeric values to the Excel API as strings. I was able to verify that this solution fixed the truncation problem. However, this is rather inconsistent, since the returned values as well as the actual values in the spreadsheet would still be numeric. Nevertheless, the Microsoft team said that fixing this would introduce some breaking changes, so we would have to live with this for now.